# SVG file. remove element

Tags: python, svg, lxml

I'm trying to remove element with id "area_3". I used something like:

```
for node in tree.xpath('//ellipse'):
    node.getparent().remove(node)
```

SVG example:

```
<svg width="600" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <image id="svg_1" y="0" x="0"/>
      <image stroke="null" xlink:href="tehplan.jpg" id="svg_5" height="587.777769" width="585.333339" y="0.578137" x="20.083334"/>
      <ellipse ry="19" rx="18" id="area_2" cy="172" cx="189" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffffff"/>
      <ellipse id="area_3" ry="19" rx="18" cy="161" cx="275" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffffff"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(open("so.svg"))
to_remove = tree.xpath("/svg:svg/svg:g/svg:ellipse[@id=\"area_3\"]",
  namespaces={"svg": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"})[0]
g = to_remove.getparent()
g.remove(to_remove)
with open("so.out.svg", "wb") as o:
    o.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

Output:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="600">
     <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <image id="svg_1" y="0" x="0"/>
      <image stroke="null" xlink:href="tehplan.jpg" id="svg_5" height="587.777769" width="585.333339" y="0.578137" x="20.083334"/>
      <ellipse ry="19" rx="18" id="area_2" cy="172" cx="189" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffffff"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```